# Is it safe to use Ubuntu when this error is presented? (mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0))

Tags: 15.10, dmesg, i915

Is it safe to use Ubuntu when this error is presented in "dmesg"? Everything is working just fine (after I have disabled processor microcode firmware).

```
[  712.259824] [drm:intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
[  712.259832] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  712.259871] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 733 at /build/linux-AxjFAn/linux-4.2.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12326 check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]()
[  712.259875] pipe state doesn't match!
[  712.259877] Modules linked in: rfcomm drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm bnep rtsx_usb_ms memstick nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media dell_led intel_rapl iosf_mbi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi arc4 snd_seq ath9k snd_seq_device snd_timer ath9k_common coretemp ath9k_hw kvm_intel snd kvm ath3k ath mac80211 btusb btrtl soundcore dell_wmi sparse_keymap btbcm cfg80211 btintel bluetooth crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 dell_laptop lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon mei_me input_leds joydev mei serio_raw dell_rbtn shpchp soc_button_array
[  712.259965]  lpc_ich mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit psmouse drm_kms_helper ahci libahci drm r8169 mii wmi video
[  712.259997] CPU: 0 PID: 733 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu
[  712.260000] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude 3540/0992HC, BIOS A05 12/24/2013
[  712.260004]  0000000000000000 00000000ce8e0daf ffff880034f177c8 ffffffff817e8c09
[  712.260011]  0000000000000000 ffff880034f17820 ffff880034f17808 ffffffff8107b3c6
[  712.260016]  ffff880034f17848 ffff880034f178b0 ffff8801288dc000 0000000000000001
[  712.260022] Call Trace:
[  712.260033]  [<ffffffff817e8c09>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[  712.260042]  [<ffffffff8107b3c6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[  712.260049]  [<ffffffff8107b455>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[  712.260083]  [<ffffffffc0196bc1>] ? intel_pipe_config_compare+0xb31/0xc60 [i915]
[  712.260113]  [<ffffffffc0196fb5>] check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]
[  712.260153]  [<ffffffffc01aad6d>] intel_modeset_check_state+0x21d/0x6d0 [i915]
[  712.260186]  [<ffffffffc01abf27>] intel_crtc_set_config+0x4c7/0x580 [i915]
[  712.260217]  [<ffffffffc0052ee5>] ? drm_mode_create+0x25/0x60 [drm]
[  712.260241]  [<ffffffffc004c4c6>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x66/0x100 [drm]
[  712.260266]  [<ffffffffc0050b29>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3e9/0x500 [drm]
[  712.260283]  [<ffffffffc0041495>] drm_ioctl+0x125/0x610 [drm]
[  712.260304]  [<ffffffffc0050740>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
[  712.260312]  [<ffffffff812108a5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x295/0x480
[  712.260320]  [<ffffffff81087f61>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
[  712.260326]  [<ffffffff81210b09>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[  712.260333]  [<ffffffff817ef9f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
[  712.260338] ---[ end trace fdc24bb5c23558d0 ]---
```

Comment: Got the same error...

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/1511101 This seems to be a related bug report

Comment: thanks... I was just wondering if it is safe to run Ubuntu with this type of error. I am not aware how serious it is... could it do any harm to my hardware?

Comment: I personally doubt that the hardware can come to a harm this way.